# Why does this code seg fault (during allocation) with pgi but not intel?

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, pgi

This code works when run on intel compiler. However when ran with pgi, it seg faults between the * and ** in the subroutine listed. I'm using pgi compiler with -mcmodel-medium. I need to use PGI to start using openacc for this code. Any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!Reading in trajectories from 'md.traj' file
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
SUBROUTINE READ_INPUT(time_i,time_f,dt,ION_COUNT,x,y,z,lf,l,nsteps)

    IMPLICIT NONE
    Integer*4, Intent(IN)                           ::time_i,time_f,dt
    Real*4,Intent(OUT),DIMENSION(:,:), Allocatable  ::x,y,z
    Real*4                                          ::vx,vy,vz
    Real*8,  Intent(OUT)                            ::lf,l
    Integer*4                                       ::time,t,j,nsteps
    Integer*4                                       ::ION_COUNT
    Character*100                                   ::filename
    Character*5                                     ::timezone
    Character*6                                     ::xfiletype
    Character*8                                     ::xcode_version,date
    Character*10                                    ::xcode_name,daytime
    Character*20                                    ::xsim_type
    Real*8                                         ::time_set,aspect(3),ev,ek,ppx,pp(9),rho
write (*,*) '*'         
    Allocate(x(1:51200,0:nsteps))
    Allocate(y(1:51200,0:nsteps))
    Allocate(z(1:51200,0:nsteps))
write (*,*) '**'

    open(UNIT=20,FILE='md.traj.00007000000.xv4b',status='OLD',form='unformatted',convert='BIG_ENDIAN')
    Do 20, time=time_i, time_f, dt
     write (*,*) time
     write(*,1001) time
1001    format ('md.',1I11.11,'.x4b')
     write (filename,1001) time
     read(20) xfiletype
     read(20) xcode_name, xcode_version
     read(20) date,daytime,timezone
     read(20) xsim_type
     read(20) time_set,rho,aspect(1),aspect(2),aspect(3),ev, ek, ppx, pp, ION_COUNT
     !rho=ION_COUNT/(xl(1)*xl(2)*xl(3))
     t=(time-time_i)/dt
```

**!Without allocating within subroutine code seg faults at this line**

```
     read (20) (x(j,t),y(j,t),z(j,t),vx,vy,vz, j=1,ION_COUNT) 
     l=(ION_COUNT/(rho))**(1.0/3.0)
    !write (*,*) x(500,5),'in read input'
     lf=(2*3.1415)/l
    20 continue

    RETURN
    END SUBROUTINE READ_INPUT
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Here's the main code

```
  Program SofQ

  Implicit NONE  
  Integer            :: time,time_u,j,i,k,OMP_NUM_THREADS
  Integer            :: t1,t3,t4,K2
  Integer            :: dw,t,time1,time2
  Real*4             :: sumbin(0:50000)
  Real*8             :: f(0:500,0:10000)
  Integer            :: Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,Qcur
  Real*4             :: CI,co(0:6537673),si(0:6537673),b(0:6537673)
  Real*8             :: dotprod,co_temp,si_temp
  Real*4             :: Qavg,zz,qmax,pfrac,nfrac
  Complex*16,Allocatable:: q(:,:)
  Complex            :: sumbin1(0:50000),sumbin2(0:50000)
  Double Precision   :: yy 
  Character          :: sofq_output,dumb
  Parameter (CI=(0,-1))
  Real*8             ::rtemp1,rtemp2,rtemp3
  Character*5        :: simtype

  Integer*4          ::p_start,p_end,nsteps

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
! Declarations for READ_INPUT
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  Integer*4                          ::time_i,time_f,dt,ION_COUNT
  Real*4,Dimension(:,:),Allocatable  ::x,y,z
  Real*8                             ::lf,l
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!Declarations for READ_VECTORS
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  Integer*4                         ::vmax,lines,i_vmax
  Integer*4, Dimension(1:6537673)   ::rx,ry,rz,mag,degen
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!Declarations for COMPUTE_SQ
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  Integer*4                         ::ions,t2
  Real*8, Allocatable               ::s(:)
  Complex*16,Allocatable            ::r(:,:)


open (UNIT=11,File='sqt_n1_gpu.dat')
write (*,*) 'begin'     
call system_clock(time1)      

  dt=20
  time_i= 7000000
  time_f= 7000500 !7050000

    nsteps=(time_f-time_i)/dt
    Allocate(x(1:51200,0:nsteps))
    Allocate(y(1:51200,0:nsteps))
    Allocate(z(1:51200,0:nsteps))  

  ION_COUNT=51200
  qmax=0.6
  simtype='pfrac'

!      OMP_NUM_THREADS=16

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Parallel Test!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!       !$OMP PARALLEL
!       write (*,*) 'Parallel?'
!       !$OMP END PARALLEL
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    CALL READ_INPUT(time_i,time_f,dt,ION_COUNT,x,y,z,lf,l,nsteps)
write (*,*) 'input'
```

So a few commenters asked about the reallocation inside the subroutine. I did this because first I tried it without the second allocation and received a segmentation fault in the subroutine when it would read in the very first x() value. I tried this again, commenting out the allocation in the subroutine and found that PGI seg faulted during the read x() and intel compiler did the same. This line is indicated with bold above.

Comment: Try using the `stat=` argument in allocate and report here what it returns.

Comment: How is this stat= argument used exactly? I tried setting it equal to a var then writing the var, but it seg faults before it writes. I put the code that I tried in the original question.

Comment: That it how it is used. Do you have all debugging options and run-time checks on? How the error message looks like? Do you have a backtrace? Did you try gdb or valgrind?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using debuggers. I found these online (-g,-gobt,-Mbounds,-v,-Mlist) and used the first one, "-g" which returned a 0 inline and some .mod files which were fairly incomprehensible to me but i can post them if they would be useful. Using the run-time check -Mbounds returned nothing.

Comment: How does the error message when crashing looks like?

Comment: aren't the x, y, z already allocated before you enter the subroutine? then you try to allocate them again.

Comment: @steabert: But should an allocatable `intent(out)` argument not be deallocated automatically? @OP What happens when you comment out the allocations in the main program (they appear to be superfluous)? This could just be a bug in the PGI compiler.

Comment: @sigma: quite true, I didn't realize that, it seemed just strange to me to allocate it outside and then again inside the routine. As far as compiler bug maybe besides removing the allocations, the OP could list the versions of the PGI/Intel compilers?

Comment: Thanks for all the info and tips. I've included the problems not allocating within the subroutine in my original post. These problems occur even using intel fortran compiler. PGI version is listed as 4.2.34, also version 4.1.40 was available: tried it with same result. Also @ Vladmir F, when crashing the message is simply "Segmentation Fault".

Answer (score 0):

When you use `intent(OUT)` for an argument that is an allocatable array, the array variable (in your case x, y and z), becomes "unallocated" at entering the subroutine. So, in this case, you HAVE to allocate it INSIDE the subroutine before starting to use it.

When you allocate the allocatable array INSIDE the subroutine, because it is associated with a dummy argument, it will not be deallocated at the end of the subroutine like it would happen if the array was a local one.

So, you can simply declare x, y and z with `intent(inout)` (or nothing, as in this case "intent(INOUT)" will have the same impact as not defining the intent) and there is no need to allocate the array again inside subroutine. Or you can allocate it only inside the routine and avoid the allocation outside it. But I think this is bad practice once it seems you want to use the arrays OUTSIDE the subroutine.

The fact that both compilers "seg fault" when you use your code without "allocating" inside the subroutine is the correct behaviour, as the arrays would be unallocated at entering the subroutine (because of the intent (out)). The fact that the PGI "seg fault" in the case you allocate the arrays "again" inside the subroutine seems to be some kind of compiler bug. In this case, allocating outside the subroutine can be the only available option if you use PGI.

Comment: It does not become undefined, it has a perfectly defined state - it is unallocated.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF.
Yes, the "correct word" for the state is "unallocated". I'll change the word in the answer.

Comment: @VladimirF, I did mean to say intent(inout). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No sorry, my error in the comment.  `intent(inout)` and "no intent specified" are different.

Comment: In fact. I changed the answer to best address this difference.

Comment: Yes, I think it is OK now, maybe with some formatting it would be more readable but that's up to you. Just not that ICE (internal compiler error) normally means an error happening during compilation when the compiler crashes. It is not just any compiler bug.

Comment: Of course!!! When the compilation fails! Duh! My bad. Thanks for the tips :) (and corrections)